# Similar functions Lookupedit.accepteditortextasnewvalue in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I am using WPF devexpress.
i want enter a value outside of the list of lookupedit and i find the answer that use combobox mode but it is for WF. And Lookupedit.accepteditortextasnewvalue in WPF.  There is another similar method? Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `LookUpEdit` this can be achieved by handling the new value (value missing from the data source) in `ProcessNewValue` event. The value inputted by user can be found in `DisplayText` property in the event args of that event. Please see DevExpress [ProcessNewValue documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.LookUpEditBase.ProcessNewValue.event) for further information:

> If the editor cannot find an item that matches the text entered by an end-user within the edit box (ProcessNewValueEventArgs.DisplayText), the ProcessNewValue event occurs. Handle this event to manually validate a new value, and if required, add the corresponding record to a data source.